# C++11 lambda - why do I need to capture auto duration variables?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

When writing a lambda function in capture '[]' part I need to specify only auto-duration variables while global and static variables are used within lambda function without needed to be captured. Why is that? Why are we not able to use auto-duration variables the same way as the global and static ones?

Comment: An automatic variable might be destroyed while the lambda still exists.

Comment: How do you mean? Destroyed while lambda is executing? Could you please provide and example for this?

Comment: Why don't you post your code that way the lifetime of the components of the lambda can be determined

Comment: @Brian that doesn't really matter though. That can also happen if you capture by reference.

Comment: @jalf That was my point exactly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because a lambda defines a separate scope: it is equivalent to this:

```
int global_i;

struct Lambda {
    Lambda(int captured_j) : captured_j(captured_j) {}
    void operator()(){
        // in this scope, global_i is accessible, and by capturing auto_j, we make that visible as well, but we can't see auto_i
    }

    int captured_j;
}

void foo() {
    int auto_i;
    int auto_j
    // this lambda
    [j](){}
    // is just shorthand for this:
    Lambda lambda(j);
}
```

The lambda is converted by the compiler into a function object (Like the `Lambda` class in my example). And the function object doesn't have access to local variables declared in the scope where the function object was instantiated. Unless you "capture" them by passing them to the constructor.

As for why the compiler doesn't do this implicitly, without requiring you to prompt it, it can't, because it doesn't know whether you want to capture by value or by reference. In GC'ed languages, you always capture by reference, because it doesn't matter -- the objects you reference stay alive as long as you need them.

But in C++, you need to manage the lifetime of those objects, and if a lambda always captured by reference, it would be virtually useless outside the scope it was declared in (because it would contain references to objects that had been destroyed). So in C++, you have to specify whether you want to capture by value or reference. And since you have to specify that, the compiler can't just do it for you.

Comment: OK. But what is foo() contains static variable? Since lambda capture does not require explicit capture for static variable how is that gonna be visible in void Lambda::operator()?

Answer (score 2):

Consider this simple function:

```
std::function<foo()> f()
{
    foo afoo;

    return [=](){ return afoo; };
}

int main()
{
    auto l = f();

    l();
}
```

If you don't capture the variable `afoo`, it goes out of scope before the closure formed by the lamda is ever used!

Also note that I used by-value capture exactly for the same reason: Returning references/pointers to local variables has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Huh? With `[=]` you capture by value, so it doesn't *matter* that `afoo` goes out of scope. It would be a problem if you used `[&]` to capture by reference, sure, but that has little to do with the OP's question of why local variables aren't *just* visible inside the lambda

Comment: @jalf _"With `[=]` you capture by value, so it doesn't matter that `afoo` goes out of scope"_ -- you just restated Manu's answer

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, there's not much magic about a lambda; simply consider it an anonymous functor.

A conventional functor would also not know about local variables where it is ctored, you'd need to provide them to its ctor. An anonymous thing like a lambda has no customizable c'tor, thus you provide context via this "[]" syntax.

Or consider

```
const float g_foo = 42.f;

struct A {
    float _bar;
    struct B {
        B() : _baz(_bar /*oops*/) {}
        float _baz;
    };
};
```

in A::B's closure there's no notion of a A's "_bar", but g_foo would be known.

Comment: Again, what about static objects that are declared locally? Why don't they need to be captured in lambda?

Comment: They are in scope for the declaration of that anonymous functor; like A's "_bar" comes in B's scope when you qualify it as static.